# Method separators

Tags: package, customize, minor-mode, display

Does anybody know of a function/package/etc. to draw visual separators between "high-level" blocks of code, like class and function definitions?  Similar to the horizontal lines in these pictures:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA "Show method separators" option]

[image: Same option in WebStorm]

I could have sworn that I was able to do this at one point, but I've been looking around for a bit and I haven't been able to find this feature.

**EDIT:** To be clear, I'm looking for a feature like ["Show method separators"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#method_navigation) in JetBrains IDEs, or like the  ["Separators"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.separators) VSCode extension.

Comment: Let me explain exactly what the OP wants, in case new answerers go down the wrong path. 1. It is something like **overline** and **underline**, but it's not a form feed. 2. These lines should be added **automatically/semantically** instead of manually. ||| Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment that you don't want to modify the existing code in any way, so you need to use what's already there.

Pick some **existing** text in your code that you think represents places where you want to show such a line.  And give it a `display` overlay property that add such an apparent line.

See the Elisp manual, these nodes:

- [Overlay Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html)
- [Display Property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Property.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the [form-feed](https://melpa.org/#/form-feed) package. Insert a page break using `C-q C-l`. When using the default full line width, then you'd probably want to enable `truncate-lines`.

Comment: While this would get the job done, I don't want to do a bunch of manual work to add each separator, and I'd prefer something that operates in a read-only fashion (e.g. I don't want to accidentally push a bunch of unprintable characters into our codebase)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a Control-L (aka Form Feed) character, using **`C-q C-l`**.

If you use library [Pretty Control-L](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettyControlL) then you can customize the appearance of the `C-l` character.

A `C-l` character separates "pages" in Emacs (and for some kinds of printing commands).  And Emacs has keys that move forward/backward among pages: **`C-x ]`** and **`C-x [`**. See the Emacs manual, node [Pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Pages.html).

Comment: While this would get the job done, I don't want to do a bunch of manual work to add each separator, and I'd prefer something that operates in a read-only fashion (e.g. I don't want to accidentally push a bunch of unprintable characters into our codebase)

Comment: You're saying you want it to recognize some **existing** text pattern that's already in your code? Your question doesn't say that (and you shouldn't "evolve" your question now). Post another question that makes clear just what you want: you have this particular text already in your code: _______ (*specify it*) and you want Emacs to present it as a horizontal line. That's a very different question from what you asked.